# Сортировка массива объектов по значению

Tags: java, массивы, циклы, объекты

Создан класс:

```
public class Employee {
    private String fullName;
    private String position;
    private String email;
    private int phoneNumber;
    private int salary;
    private byte age;

        //геттеры и сеттеры
    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }
    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }
    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public int getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }
    public void setPhoneNumber(int phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public byte getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(byte age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    //параметризированный конструктор 
    public Employee(String fullName, String position, String email, int phoneNumber, int salary, byte age) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.position = position;
        this.email = email;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.age = age;
    }
```

В другом классе создан массив:

```
public class EmployeeDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee [] mas = new Employee[5];
        mas[0] = new Employee("KozlovAA", "developer", "kozlovaa@mail.ru", 123456, 10000, (byte) 30);
        mas[1] = new Employee("IvanovAA", "engineer", "IvanovAA@mail.ru", 321654, 15000, (byte) 35);    
        mas[2] = new Employee("PetrovEE", "manager", "PetrovEE@mail.ru", 234651, 8000, (byte) 40);  
        mas[3] = new Employee("SidorovAA", "seller", "SidorovAA@mail.ru", 654321, 7000, (byte) 45); 
        mas[4] = new Employee("AbramovichRO", "businessman", "AbramovichRO@mail.ru", 112233, 100000, (byte) 50); 
    }   
}
```

Нужно в классе EmployeeDemo создать метод который c помощью цикла выведет на консоль все объекты этого массива у которых поле age > 40;
Данный метод не работает - подскажите пожалуйста что делаю не так?

```
public void sortOfAge() {
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
        if (this.getAge() > 40) {
            System.out.println("ФИО: " + fullName);
            System.out.println("должность: " + position);
            System.out.println("email: " + email);
            System.out.println("телефон: " + phoneNumber);
            System.out.println("зарплата: " + salary);
            System.out.println("возраст: " + age);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В методе `sortOfAge` нужно проитерироваться по массиву и выбрать для отображения только те, которые удовлетворяют критерию. Т.е. должно быть что то такое:

```
for(Employee employee: array){
    if(employee.age<40){
        System.out.println("ФИО: " + fullName);
        System.out.println("должность: " + position);
        System.out.println("email: " + email);
        System.out.println("телефон: " + phoneNumber);
        System.out.println("зарплата: " + salary);
        System.out.println("возраст: " + age);
    }
}
```

Или в более функциональном стиле:

```
Arrays
      .stream(employees)
      .filter(e -> e.age > 40)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Arrays
      .stream(employees)
      .filter(e -> e.age > 40)
      .forEach(System.out::println); от этого я ещё далёк :(

Comment: Проблема в том что я из метода не вижу массив mas и не пойму как обратиться к полю age 
 `public void sortOfAge() {
 for(Employee employee: mas){
     if(employee.age<40){
         System.out.println("ФИО: " + fullName);
         System.out.println("должность: " + position);
         System.out.println("email: " + email);
         System.out.println("телефон: " + phoneNumber);
         System.out.println("зарплата: " + salary);
         System.out.println("возраст: " + age);
     }
 }`

Comment: определите метод так public static void sortOfAge(Employee[]array), тогда  вызвать из метода main его можно будет так: sortOfAge(mass)

Comment: Точно, получилось, спасибо огромное. И подскажите пожалуйста, а как обратиться к полю age?     if(employee.age<40) - такой код не работает - я так понимаю из-за того что переменная age инкапсулирована, а как её сравнить с значением 40 через геттер, да ещё и в массиве не пойму.

Comment: По-моему, в первом коде должно так: `employee.getAge() > 40` - знак "больше". И в обоих случаях `.getAge()`, а не `.age`.